# Making swipe work for a pivot control with embedded WebBrowser on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

I'd like my application to have a `Pivot` control with a `WebBrowser` control in each `PivotItem`. The problem is that swiping to next `PivotItem` doesn't work since it instead results in scrolling the web page horizontally. However, the web pages are responsive and doesn't need to be scrolled horizontally so instead I want horizontal swiping to result in a pivot switch. Can this be accomplished? If I can't use a `Pivot` control what is the recommended way to implement page switching with `WebControl`s on the pages? A top menu a la iOS/Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, however needs little workaround since Webbrowser handles the event first and your Pivot probably doesn't know about it. You can use for this purpose `Touch` and its event `FrameReported`. Simple code can look like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

TouchPoint first;

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
   TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(myWebBrowser);
   if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
         first = mainTouch;
   else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up)
   {
       if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X < 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Next item.");
           //myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
       if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X > 0)
           MessageBox.Show("Previous item.");
          //myPivot.SelectedIndex--;
   }
}
```

As you can see - I'm remembering the where the user start his movements, then when he releases his touch - I change myPivot.SelectetIndex. Hope this helps a little. You can also try with `TouchPanel`, but I think that will be simpler (if it's sufficient).

---

If you want to disable some gestures it can look for example like in the code below. I enabled only HorizontalDrag - so it won't fire for zoom. The tolerance of course shouldn't be 0, you will have to define the most suitable for your App.

```
// in MainPage() constructor
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.HorizontalDrag; 

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
   TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(myMap);
   if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
        first = mainTouch;
   else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up && TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
      if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X < 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Next item.");
        //myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
      if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Previous item.");
        //myPivot.SelectedIndex--;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While this works in principle it will need another tolerance than zero for the horizontal swipe conditions since vertical scrolling probably will trigger a pivot change (unless you scroll _exactly_ vertical). So the question is what tolerance to use in the condition? Also zooming and pinching will also trigger a pivot change I imagine.

Comment: @Christian I've edited a little code, so that it won't fire for Zoom. You will probably figure out more with other gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article that solves this particular issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2015/02/11/how-to-embed-a-webbrowser-control-inside-a-pivot-item-in-windows-phone.aspx