# how to detect the horizontal change when swiping inside a pivot control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I would like to detect the horizontal change when swiping inside a pivot control in windows phone 8 so that i can make changes to the collection bound to the control, like add or remove items when swiping left or right. I want something other than selectionchanged event as i am facing some problem there.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of `FrameReported` event - example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21598176/2681948).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public TakeTourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GestureListener gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(ContentPanel);
    gestureListener.DragCompleted += gestureListener_DragCompleted;
}

void gestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
{

    // User flicked towards left
    if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
    {
    }

    // User flicked towards right
    if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener' is obsolete: 'GestureListener is obsolete beginning in Windows Phone 8, as the built-in manipulation and gesture events on UIElement now have functional parity with it.'

Comment: still if you want to use, you can use it or you should go for manipulation events for windows phone